# electron ES6 code Unexpected token import

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6, electron

Development electron app.

use zhe ES6 code in html  is success.
but write ES6 code in alone js fail is error.

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "main": "main.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.3.0",
    "react-dom": "^15.3.0"
  }
}
```

index.html  in electron is success

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>STW</title>
    <script src="js/browser.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="container">
</div>
<script type="text/babel">
    import React,{Component} from 'react';
    import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
//    import FF from'./Foo.js';
    class F1 extends Component{
        render(){
            return <div>This is React component</div>
        }
    };
    ReactDOM.render(<F1/>,document.getElementById("container"))


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

when i use `import FF from'./Foo.js';`it's error and show  "Unexpected token import".

Foo.js

```
import React from 'react'

export default class Foo extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return <div>This is React  component</div>
    }
}
```

electron is latest version.

ES6 code in html `<script type="text/babel">` is success,
How can i use zhe ES6 code in alone file ? thanks =.=

Comment: you have to transpile `import`. it's not supported yet in browsers.

Answer (score 0):

As for my knowledge, support for ES6 modules first needs to land in V8. For now you have to use:

```
const ReactDOM = require('react-dom')
```

Comment: thanks,I use zhe webpack now ,give up this problem=.=,it's to trouble